# extern NSString *const in a class.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, extern

Hi I've got this header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PCConstants : NSObject
extern NSString *const kPCUserProfileKey;
extern NSString *const kPCUserProfileNameKey;
extern NSString *const kPCUserProfileFirstNameKey;
extern NSString *const kPCUserProfileLocationKey;
extern NSString *const kPCUserProfileGenderKey;
extern NSString *const kPCUserProfileBirthDayKey;
extern NSString *const kPCUserProfileInterestedInKey;
@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "PCConstants.h"

@implementation PCConstants

NSString *const kPCUserProfileKey                  = @"profile";
NSString *const kPCUserProfileNameKey              = @"name";
NSString *const kPCUserProfileFirstNameKey         = @"firstname";
NSString *const kPCUserProfileLocationKey          = @"location";
NSString *const kPCUserProfileGenderKey            = @"gender";
NSString *const kPCUserProfileBirthDayKey          = @"birthday";
NSString *const kPCUserProfileInterestedInKey      = @"interestedIn";

@end
```

When I import the header file in my .pch file, I can access the constants everywhere. But I try to understand what's going on.

I never alloc init this object, so they can't be instance constants. So the constants must be "class object constants right? But I thought class objects could not contain data.

Can someone explain?

Comment: AFAIK Objective C doesn't support instance-level constants. So your constants are probably treated as having a file scope. Which is consistent with the behavior that you see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those `extern` variables are app-level globals. They are not scoped to the class and they are not scoped to an instance of the class.

Objective-C does not support instance or class level globals.

If you want class level constants, you need to define class methods to access them. If you want instance level constants, you need to define instance methods or read-only properties to access them.

Comment: Ok, so they have nothing to do with the class.... So its not an object, they are constant pointers to mutable objects.

Comment: Actually, I believe that it is technically possible to add an ivar to a class using the run time and the meta-class. Not that I would recommend it...

Comment: @pic-o-matic: They are constant pointers to *immutable* objects (constant NSStrings, to be precise).