# iOS and XCode: What is the best way to store connection settings (i.e. URLs) for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, url, connection, settings, plist

We started with #defines pointing our app to dev, qa and live API servers.  Well, that's rather lazy, not to mention painful to manage.

I'm thinking of storing default URL/connection settings in a .plist and creating dev|stage|live build configurations that will use the corresponding .plist for connections.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?
How secure is a .plist?

Comment: Not secure at all. If you want a more secure way, you could build your URL string at runtime grabbing each character out of an array. This way, the binary doesn't contain the string. (Most people don't bother to look at a binary however, only people with too much time on their hands)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I handle it.

I have a single file where i store information like this.  Lets call this file Configuration{h,m}

Within my .h (header) file, i declare the constants like this:

```
#pragma mark - API
extern NSString * const kAPIHost;
extern NSString * const kAPIVersion;
```

Within my .m (implementation) file, I finish it off with this

```
#pragma mark - API

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
NSString * const kAPIHost = @"http://localhost/";
#else
NSString * const kAPIHost = @"http://liveserver.com";
#endif

NSString * const kAPIVersion = @"v2/";
```

What happens here is, it checks to see if i'm running on the sim, if i am, then it uses localhost, if it's running on device, it uses the live server.

Finally, I import Configuration.h in my precompiled header (PCH) file.

```
#import Configuration.h
```

Now, this file is available throughout your application without needing to import it in every single file.  I use it like this.

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[kAPIHost stringByAppendingString:[kAPIVersion stringByAppendingString:@"apiEndPoint/"]]];
```

The comment that troop231 posted sounds very interesting though.  Maybe something I can implement at some time in the future.  Always looking for more secure ways to do things :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  How do you handle builds against Staging vs. Production servers?  More #ifdefs?  Why not use a .plist?

Answer (score 1):

You could store this in keychain - it's secure - but I don't know why You would want to do that.

You could use extern constants instead of defines:
[extern NSString *const in a class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540166/extern-nsstring-const-in-a-class)

You can use preprocessor directives to help You manage the addresses:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Objective-C_Preprocessor_Directives

You could create a singleton class that would for example read these urls from .plist at start and then hand it over to any class that is interested.

About security:

- using singleton with .plist and shipping app would not reveal Your test / dev addresses.
- using #define, externs and preprocessor directives i.e. #ifdef DEBUG would also not reveal Your dev / test addresses in production code.